# How can I remove the editor from the 'main posts page'?

Tags: post-editor

I'm trying (and failing - despite the numerous previous posts by others) to more easily/reliably remove the content editor from this page.

I can remove it using the page-ID:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_editor' );

function hide_editor() {

if( isset( $_GET['post'] ) && $_GET['post'] == '7' ) // '7' is the ID of the page ID.
remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}
```

But I'd prefer to remove it according to template used - in this instance, the default 'home.php'.

I've tried various conditionals, variants of 'get_page_template' and 'is_page_template' - none of which work... I suspect because the page uses a default rather than selected template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress already does this by default, so long as that page doesn't have any existing content. Plus it adds a notice explaining why the editor isn't there.

These are the lines already in WordPress Core:

```
if ( $post_ID == get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) && empty( $post->post_content ) ) {
    add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', '_wp_posts_page_notice' );
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor' );
}
```

Lines 74-76 here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php

Comment: thanks. I'd wondered why one of my installs did this, but another didn't - I now understand that's because 'if doesn't have any existing content' (for years, to reduce potential misunderstandings, I've added an 'anything here won't display' message to the editor.